# Change default function of object

Tags: javascript

I have this simple object, that I got in my example from someone else: (I cannot change the object source code)

```
var a=function(){
   console.log('original')
}
a.p=true
```

Is it possibile in Javascript to change the default function of `a object` without rebuild the object?

If I am doing

```
 a=function(){'other function'}
```

I lost the `p` property (`p == undefined`)

I know that I can copy, or extend, I am searching for the most simple solution.

I have try:

```
 a.prototype.constructor=function(){console.log('new function')}
 a.constructor=function(){console.log('new function')}
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: The "property" is a part of the function. What you're basically trying to do is "copy all the members of this function, except for the body" - maybe `for` would be good enough for you? Why do you want to change the "constructor" in the first place?

Comment: Copy all properties to the new function? But seriously, I smell really bad design here...

Answer (score 0):

You can use prototype and maintain the old functionality as well as add the new one.

```
a.constructor.prototype.test = function(){console.log('test');};

a();       //logs original
a.p;       //prints true
a.test();  //logs test
```